# Why does static allocation of memory not work when declaring nodes to create a linklist

Tags: c++, list, function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
    node(){}
    node(int data){
        this->data=data;
        this->next=NULL;
    }

};
node* createlinklist(){
    node*head=new node();
    int data;
    cout<<"Enter data and -1 to exit"<<endl;
    cin>>data;
    if(data!=-1){
        head->data=data;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    node* it=head;
    cin>>data;
    while(data!=-1){
        node* temp;
        temp->data=data;
        temp->next=NULL;
        it->next=temp;
        it=it->next;
        cin>>data;
    }
    return head;
}
void print(node* head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        cout<<head->data<<"-->";
        head=head->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
}
```

For the code above when I dynamically allocate memory for temp and do node* temp=new node(); the linklist prints perfectly but when I do the above in the way I posted the code it just doesn't work after the first node. From all my studying it seems that dynamic allocation shouldn't make a difference at all in this context, right? I'm not using the statically allocated nodes out of the scope of the function so I don't understand why it doesn't print if I don't use dynamic allocation for temp.

Comment: `node* temp; temp->data = data;` is undefined behavior. `temp` is *unallocated garbage* and isn't pointing at anything.

Comment: `node* temp;`is a pointer. Pointers are useless if they don't point at a valid object (or a safe parking value like `nullptr` that can be used in a test). You must provide that object one way or another and dynamic allocation is the way that makes the best sense here.

Comment: The point is that you don't have any statically allocated nodes. `node* temp;` is a pointer, not a node.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) debugger. Enable all warnings & debug info when compiling (on Linux, use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)

Comment: PS although I know what you mean, you are confusing terminology, what you are calling static allocation, is actually automatic allocation. Static means something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point, it's called automatic allocation not static allocation.

Second point, this code is undefined behaviour because it uses an uninitalised pointer

```
while (data != -1) {
    node* temp;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    it->next = temp;
    it = it->next;
    cin>>data;
}
```

Here `temp` is not given a value, so using it like this `temp->data` is an error. This has nothing to do with types of allocation. The problem is that nothing has been allocated, by any means, for `temp` to point to.

Third point, lets try and fix the above problem with automatic allocation, you could write this code and it would compile

```
while (data != -1) {
    node auto_node;
    node* temp = &auto_node; // a pointer to an automatically allocated object
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    it->next = temp;
    it = it->next;
    cin>>data;
}
```

This code would most likely crash when run. The reason is that you **are** using the `auto_node` objects outside of the function. This maybe is your real misunderstanding. Although you are not using the `auto_node` objects directly, you have retained pointers to those objects, all the `next` pointers in your linked list are pointing at these automatically allocated nodes which don't exist outside of your `createlinklist` function.